# Construyendo funciones en Rstudio

Tags: r

A partir de la data (Cereal) en Lock5data ¿Cómo puedo crear una función que al suministrarle los argumentos: calories y fat muestre como salida el nombre del cereal?

Por ejemplo: supongamos que ya se ha creado dicha función que tiene por nombre **Hojuelas** y al aplicarla:

```
library(Lock5Data)
data(Cereal)
Hojuelas(Cereal, calories =117, fat= 0.6)
```

Debería arrojar como resultado:

```
"Applejacks"
```

el cual corresponde al cereal para esos argumentos específicos

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a usar los datos exactos para ubicar el Cereal, puedes hacer esto:

```
Hojuelas <- function(Cereal, calories, fat) {
    return(as.character(Cereal[Cereal$Calories == calories & Cereal$Fat == fat,]$Name))
}

Hojuelas(Cereal, calories = 117, fat = 0.6)
[1] "AppleJacks"
```

Por supuesto, no sirve para ubicar por aproximación, pero entiendo que no es lo que pides.

Comment: Hola Patricio, tengo una duda con respecto a la función anterior, como puedo hacer para que ademas del nombre del cereal, esa misma función me retorne el nombre de la compañia (company)?

Comment: Puede modificar la función para que devuelva un data.frame con las columnas que necesites así: `return(Cereal[Cereal$Calories == calories & Cereal$Fat == fat,c("Name", "Company")])`

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias