# Creando una función que genere una tabla como output

Tags: r, rstudio

A partir  la data Cereal de **Lock5Data**  Cómo podria hacer una función que me de como output una tabla con las calorias (Calories) y el nombre de la compañia (Company) con introducirle a esa función  el nombre del cereal.

Por ejemplo, supongamos tengo la siguiente función:

```
     Cereales20 <- (Cereal, name == "AppleJacks")
```

y quiero obtener esto:

```
           Name      Company  Calories                
    AppleJacks           K      117 0.6
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

hace unos días te respondí [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79101/construyendo-funciones-en-rstudio) cuya solución es bastante parecida a esta. Cuando hablas de tabla imagino que estás hablando de un `data.frame`, `Cereal` ya es un `data.frame`, con lo cual lo único que en realidad debes hacer es:

- Filtrar aquellos cuyo `name == <nombre>`
- Mostrar solo las columnas que mencionas `Name`, `Company` y `Calories`

Esto en R es tan sencillo como hacer esto:

```
Cereal[Cereal$Name == "AppleJacks", c("Name", "Company", "Calories")]
```

De todas formas, la función:

```
require(Lock5Data)
data("Cereal")

Cereales20 <- function(Cereal, name) {
    return(Cereal[Cereal$Name == name,c("Name", "Company", "Calories")])
}

Cereales20(Cereal, name = "AppleJacks")

        Name Company Calories
1 AppleJacks       K      117
```